# Why is module.export return undefined when the object is a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am quite new to nodejs. I am using a small library 'cukefarm'. And the file structure looks like below.

```
index.js
lib/support/World.js
lib/protractor.conf.js
```

index.js looks like:

```
World = require('./lib/support/World');
config = require('./lib/protractor.conf');

module.exports = {
  World: World,
  config: config
}
```

World.js looks like:

```
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');

function World() {
  this.Q = require('q');

  this.currentPage = null;
  this.pageObjectMap = null;

  chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
  this.expect = chai.expect;
};

module.exports = World;

console.log('\n' + __filename);
console.log('World ' + JSON.stringify(World, null, "  "));
```

protractor.conf.js looks like:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  framework: 'custom',
  frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
  capabilities: {
    'chromeOptions': {
      args: ['--test-type']
    }
  },
  cucumberOpts: {
    require: [
      path.resolve('./node_modules/cukefarm/lib/step_definitions/GeneralStepDefs'),
      path.resolve('./node_modules/cukefarm/lib/support/Transform'),
      path.resolve('./node_modules/cukefarm/lib/support/World')
    ],
    format: []
  },
  onPrepare: function() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(5000);
    return browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000);
  }

};

console.log('\n' + __filename);
console.log('module.exports ' + JSON.stringify(module.exports, null, "  "));
```

I try to console log the exports object in both World.js and protractor.conf.js.

protractor.conf works fine, it prints the object no problem.

But World shows log as:

> World undefined

P.S. the complete code of 'cukefarm' is located at https://github.com/ReadyTalk/cukefarm

Comment: should not you console.log(new Word())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are consoled wrong, You had `stringified` function not the `object`

```
const World = require("./env");

console.log(JSON.stringify(World, null, 4)); // undefined
console.log("World " + JSON.stringify(World, null, "  ")); // World undefined
console.log(JSON.stringify(new World(), null, 4)); // test
```

// env.js

```
module.exports = function() {
    console.log("test")
}
```

Comment: however, the function in my example is a 'object constructor function' while in your example it's a normal 'function', can you use a 'new' operator to a normal function?

Comment: It same, i was just giving example. constructor is new ES6 way